What does "Kino Hanim" mean? How is it written?
Reaching the edges of on topic with this one.
In the song "Brazil" by kkluv @ ~1:38, there's the line:




现在你是我 KINO HANIM (电影女主)

For the longest time I assumed Kino Hanim was the name of an actual person. Now, I am thinking that it is Uyghur for actress or something along those lines.
My best estimation of actress, though, seems to be something along the lines of:

ئارتىس

(See [Dilraba Dilmurat]'s Uyghur Wiki page for instance.4)
Which looks to just be a transliteration approximation of the English word "artist."
Ideas?

I thought about this again, and "KINO HANIM" is probably a title for a person in this context (like King of Kings, The First Emperor, The Boy Who Lived) with some special significance, otherwise they would not have bothered to use "KINO HANIM" rather than use 電影女主 directly.

Wow, this is highly off-topic - I can't spin any Chinese into this at all, but let's take it as a general language research question.
If this is indeed Uyghur, I guess it should be written as "كىنو خانىم", and it just means the item in the parentheses (電影女主).
As you may know, Uyghur is a Turkic language, in the same family as Turkish and Uzbek. It's then a safe bet to assume that they would share cultural spheres and thus a large portion of vocabulary.

If you Google "hanim", the top results for me point to Turkish hanım (wife, lady)
If you check "kino" on Wiktionary, you get an Uzbek entry which means (cinema, film).

I then asked ChatGPT the following:

What is the Uyghur cognate of Turkish "hanım"?

The Uyghur cognate of the Turkish word hanım (meaning "lady" or "madam") is خانىم. In Uyghur, it is similarly used as a respectful title for women.


What is the Uyghur cognate of Uzbek "kino"?

The Uyghur cognate of the Uzbek word kino (meaning "movie" or "film") is  كىنو. In both languages, this term is borrowed from Russian кино, itself a short form of кинематограф (kinematograf), which means "cinematograph."



Basic verification of these two words on Wiktionary:

خانىم (xanim) appears in a translation of English "madam" in Wiktionary
كىنو (kino) appears directly as a Wiktionary entry


My only saving grace is how large of an umbrella 方言 can be in Chinese.
